# Is splitting an Access database necessary to support multiple concurrent users?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have created a database in MS Access 2010 for my company. 
We have a network drive where multiple users has access to files and applications.
Can i put the database on this network without having to split the database?

Comment: No you cannot. Put the back-end on the network and a front-end on each users PC.

Comment: @Fionnuala: You're mistaken. Links in my answer.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I am not mistaken. There are things you can do, but you absolutely should not do them.

Comment: "No you cannot" and "There are better ways" are two different things. You absolutely should not confuse them.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' effectively, you cannot.

Comment: Fionnuala - I will bet you $1M(US) that I can put an Access database on a network without splitting it.  Will you accept that bet?  If not, then your answer is wrong.  And, your answer is wrong.

Comment: I think at this point this entire Q&A session has devolved into a semantics argument.  I think the Poster has more than enough information to go on  :-)

Comment: @bones: Of course you "can". The implicit question is, if it will work for an extended time, and sooner or later it will not, while - if splitting the database - it will work. We have many clients running this scenario with zero issues (one for fourteen years), while I have seen concurrent use of a common non-split database fail after a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Split the database (do make a backup first) and move the backend to the server folder while copying the frontend to the users' local drives.

Comment: This one I agree with :)

Comment: After doing this, migrate the back end data to a "real" database for a huge performance boost (typically about 100x by real world measurements at a fortune 500 company).

Comment: @pojo-guy So who is to maintain the 'real' back-end in a 5 person company?

Comment: @Gustav: You're mistaken. See link in my answer.

Comment: What is the simplest way to do a back and front end? Having the tables in a database file on the server and the user interface on the local pc? And then link all users to the database? Is that better and why?

Comment: @mike. Sorry, my answer is correct. And you misread the MS support note.

Comment: @Fionnuala The thing about a real back end database is it is EASIER to maintain over time than Access.  My current company, which is about 5 people, is not a good comparison because database maintenance is one of our products.  However, I can say from experience that switching from Access to anything (except DB2) reduced my datbase maintenance time.

Comment: @Fionnuala if you have someone to write a access db for a 5 person company yet they don't have the required skills to migrate the actual database to something more stable then that person should either be working for free or there is something seriously wrong ... As for maintenance ? Really ? Your pulling that card when comparing anything against access ? ( now don't get my wrong I have most likely earned over 100k over the years as a consultant simply on fixing access applications after catastrophic failure, and for a long long time I have simply refused to work in windows shops..)

Comment: @Gustav Wouldnt it be more suitable to put the frondtend on the network drive if the administrator wants to change the layout of a form?

Comment: @EmilOlsen Yes, that is the correct path.  With this configuration, one machine is managing record concurrency and the underlying file system, so the risk of corruption is reduced enormously and performance is the best Access can offer.  At this point, you are also set up to take the next step in performance and stability by switching out the access back end for something "real".

Comment: @Fred You still run into concurrency problems when you do this.  You are better served by having a nightly process to copy the front end to the local box than keeping a single copy on the server.

Comment: @Fred. No. The developer keeps his copy off-line. When a new version is ready, it is copied to a common network read-only folder from which users pull a copy to a local folder.Manually or by a script.

Answer (score -1):

MS access database and network, or concurrent writes are a recipe for disaster. I am speaking from experience here..

Yes you can put it on the network, but in the long run you will see data corruption occur if it has any serious usage. (also on that note it will also hit some 'hard limits' once tables become too large running the risk of permanently locking you out of your data. )

Comment: Speaking from my own experience, I have only had one problem, and that not even on a network, in more than 20 years. There are limits to Access, but for a small company it works very well.

Comment: @Fionnuala I agree, I think Access has just gotten a bad name because of the amount of shoddy databases that have been created by non-developers.

Comment: @Fionnuala My first 'professional' work with MS Access was circa 2003, while I don't work with MS technologies anymore, in those few years I would have to say I have seen half a dozen projects which simply exploded due to indexing errors caused by concurrent IO the locking mechanisms are simply average at best. I would recommend creating a ODBC connection to something a little more serious. I have seen these failures even in 'professional' accounting/pos products (see: created by real developers.)

Comment: I supported an access product that was core to profits for a fortune 500 company during a period of explosive growth.  For all of the technical issues we had against Access, one could not argue against its cost effectiveness.

With that said, migrating the back end to a "real" database typically gives an instant performance boost of two orders of magnitude - that's somewhat better than minutes to seconds for the mathematically declined - and does not involve a lot of rewrite on the front end - the biggest thing is getting the date and time related stuff sorted out.

Comment: @pojo-guy MS-Access frontend with FirebirdSQL->ODBC bridge on the back is effectively free and avoids 90% of the access related hassle. (p.s. ever have to deal with a compact & rebuild operation 'lose' a days worth of transactions or having to archive every 3 months to avoid corruption ? )

Comment: No one defined the size of the user base.  I concur with Damian that serious use of Access in a network scenario is a recipe for disaster.  At about 10 concurrent live users, which is not anywhere near serious use, Access tends to lock and lag even on small databases.

Comment: @DamianNikodem I'm quite familiar with firebird.  Jim Starkey architected quite a nice system, and contributed a LOT to the industry as a whole.  I switched to Postgresql because Firebird converts numbers over 1,000,000 to doubles, which loses precision.  You can't use Firebird for tracking money.

Comment: @DamianNikodem I feel like that is making the assumption that the OP's setting is going to require tons of input with many many concurrent users.

Comment: @DamianNikodem Multiple <> Many.  I am currently running a database with 20+ concurrent users with heavy input daily.  I simply make sure I maintain a good backup system and perform my frequent compact and repairs.  Over the past year I have only had 3 record corrupted records which were easily recovered.

Comment: @Newd You could easily scale that product 100 times or more and reduce you workload by replacing the backend Access with real RDBMS.  This is actually Microsoft's scaling recommendation (their target is SQL Server).  Most commercial RDBMS' have a free version that you can use on single CPU (including SQL server), and there are several competitive open source products that you can use for free (firebird and Postgres have both been referenced in this thread).

Comment: @pojo-guy I agree, this is definitely a "Work with what you have" scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can put it on the network without splitting the database, but that's usually not the best way to share an Access database.

[Ways to share an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74) (from Microsoft support)

> **Split database**     This is a good choice if you do not have a SharePoint site or a database server product. . . .
>
> **Network folder**    This is the simplest option, but it also offers the least functionality. The database file is stored on a shared
>   network drive, and people use the database file simultaneously.
>   Reliability and availability can become issues if there are multiple
>   simultaneous users changing data. All database objects are shared.
>
> **SharePoint site**    This is a good option if you have a server running Windows SharePoint Services. . . .

Comment: Not only is it not a good way to share, it is a recipe for disaster. It is like saying yes, you can park here, your car will fit in that no parking zone :)

Comment: And yet skilled Access developers have avoided disaster for decades. (shrug)

Comment: *"you can put it on the network without splitting the database, but that's usually not the best way to share an Access database."* - That is **never** a good way to share an Access database among multiple concurrent users. *"[Microsoft Support says] Reliability and availability can become issues if there are multiple simultaneous users changing data."* - That is residual understatement of the problem that Microsoft avoided talking about for years. When supporting multiple concurrent users, *always* split the database and *never* share the same copy of the front-end.

Comment: @GordThompson The voice of reason, it is so hard to get this across.

Comment: Solely for the sake of argument.  The part about "Concurrent users" was added in an edit and is a bit of an assumption that people will be accessing the database at the same time.  While I still don't ever see the purpose in not splitting the database unless you are the sole user, I just thought I would throw that out there.

Comment: I'm going to +1 because technically this is the best answer.  Remember, the OP asked if it was *necessary*.  it is not *necessary*.  You can run it without splitting it.  However, it is *not the best way*, which this answer clearly states.